# Custom Dropdown Search Bar working everywhere but IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am just getting into javascript and Web Development as a former .NET Desktop App guy and I am struggling with figuring out what is causing issues for me with Internet Explorer (Not working on 11).  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Greatly Appreciate any help! Also and advice on what to avoid to support IE.

When Debugging in IE11 Im getting an error on my search filter:
"Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'"

```
// check for min length
if (filter.length < 3) {
    $('#dropdownItems').append("<li><a>Please input at least 3 characters.</a></li>");
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (playerDatabase[i].name.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
            $('#dropdownItems').append("<li><a href='playerPage.html?playerID=" + playerDatabase[i].playerID +"'>" + playerDatabase[i].name + " - " + playerDatabase[i].pos + "</a></li>");
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Snippet**

```js
var playerDatabase = [];
var count;

// Data Load Event
function showModal() {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      playerDatabase = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      count = $(playerDatabase).toArray().length;
    }
  };

  var requestURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maat7043/sportssabermetrics/master/playerDatabase.json';
  xmlhttp.open("GET", requestURL, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};


// Search Bar Filter Logic
function searchPlayers() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("searchBarInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("dropdownItems");
  li = div.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // remove all current items
  for (i = li.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    div.removeChild(li[i]);
  }

  // check for min length
  if (filter.length < 3) {
    $('#dropdownItems').append("<li><a>Please input at least 3 characters.</a></li>");
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (playerDatabase[i].name.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
        $('#dropdownItems').append("<li><a href=http://www.sportssabermetrics.net/html/player-analyzer/playerPage.html?playerID=" + playerDatabase[i].playerID + ">" + playerDatabase[i].name + " - " + playerDatabase[i].pos + "</a></li>");
      }
    }
  }
}

// Search Bar focus lost
$(document).on("focusout", "#searchBarInput input", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("dropdownItems");
  var li = div.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // remove all current items
  for (i = li.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    div.removeChild(li[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
/* * Copyright (c) 2012 Thibaut Courouble
 * Licensed under the MIT License
   ================================================== */

a {
  color: #1e7ad3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

input {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search input {
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
  background: #555860;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus+.results,
.search .results:hover {
  display: block
}

.search .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li {
  display: block;
}

.search .results li:first-child {
  margin-top: -1px
}

.search .results li:first-child:before,
.search .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before,
.search .results li:first-child:hover:after {
  display: none
}

.search .results li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px
}

.search .results a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  text-color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span {
  font-weight: 200
}

.search .results a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}

.search .results a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input {
  line-height: 26px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Sports Sabermetrics</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.sportssabermetrics.net/html/images/icon.png">

  <!-- W3 Schools CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.0.0-18/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onpageshow="showModal()" style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="top-bar no-padding" style="height: 100vh; background-image: url(http://www.sportssabermetrics.net/html/images/header_image.jpg); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="w3-display-middle w3-center" style="width:60%;">
      <!-- Search Bar -->
      <section class="main">
        <div id="myDropdown" style="margin: auto; font-size: 14px;">
          <form class="search" method="post"><input type="text" id="searchBarInput" placeholder="Search for NFL Player" onkeyup="searchPlayers()"/>
            <ul id="dropdownItems" class="results">
            </ul>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), IE does not support the `includes` method. You can use `indexOf` instead:

```
if (playerDatabase[i].name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) { ... }
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of browser compatability issues ;)

Comment: Alternatively, polyfills exist.